# Dropbox OAuth2 login page broken when shown in Google App Script Dialog Box

Tags: google-apps-script, dropbox-api

I'm trying to perform OAuth2 login from Google Spreadsheet script.
I'm sending a request to https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize, getting a valid response and displaying a Dropbox login page using

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opts).getContentText();
HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dropbox Login');
```

The problem is that after I enter user name and password, the Login button remains disabled. I tried all the three possible sandbox modes.

Comment: Is JavaScript enabled? (It's required for the Dropbox site to work properly.) If so, are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at google app scripts state tokenbuilder? Its meant to be used for OAuth2.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/state-token-builder

Also look at this github for an example:
https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2